# Did I correctly implement PSNR calculation code in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is the following code a correct way of calculating PSNR for grayscale images in Matlab?

```
function p = psnr(x,y, vmax)

if nargin<3
    m1 = max( abs(x(:)) );
    m2 = max( abs(y(:)) );
    vmax = max(m1,m2);
end

d = mean( (x(:)-y(:)).^2 );

p = 10*log10( vmax^2/d );
```

For 8-bit input, `vmax=255`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, according to the [Wikipedia article about Peak signal-to-noise ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio), your code is a faithful implementation of PSNR; it corresponds directly to the first definition given there.

In case `vmax` is not given, you could also imagine using [`intmax`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/intmax.html) to determine it for a given data type (depending on your application; your implementation also makes sense).